# How can I left-join two datasets multiple times with each time using a different variable as a key?

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join

I am combining two dataframes using left_join as I need to keep all the rows from `X` and only matched ones from `Y`. However, there is no one column which provides a perfect match. Instead there is 1 column in `X` which partially matches 2 columns in `Y`, and a second column in `X` which partially matches a third column in `Y`. Only by matching on all 3 can I adequately merge the data since they all match on different combinations of rows (with some overlap).

My strategy so far has been to do three seperate `left_join` commands, each with a different match. Doing this enables me to match about 95% of the rows (the first match only gets about 70%). However, this leaves me with three versions of each column from `Y` in the merged data. I have tried using paste and a number of other ways to combine them, but either it hasn't worked or the new columns aren't helpful as they are concatenated (e.g. showing "12345 NA 12345" or "NA NA NA"). I need it to show only the first non-NA result as all non-NA results will be identical. So for the two examples above I would want to return only "12345" and "NA".

So I think I either need to figure out how to do a left_join on multiple columns (This doesn't work, but something like:

```
left_join(X, Y, by = (c("Column1" = Column1) OR c("Column1" = "Column2") OR c( Column 2, Y = "Column 3")).
```

Or, less elegantly, I just need to figure out how to reformat the merged/ pasted column to keep only the first non-NA result.

In the example below, X has 2 columns and 5 rows and Y has 4 columns and 7 rows (5 of which match the rows in X). The only way to merge X and Y fully is to match X$Column1 with Y$Column1 OR Y$Column2, OR X$Column2 with Y$Column3. In the real data there are around 50,000 rows in `X` and also lots of other columns in `X` and `Y`). The desired output from the below should be the five rows from X (which also have matches in Y), along with the corresponding values in Y$Column4.

```
X$Column1 = c(10, 150, 3550, 9421, 22000)
X$Column2 = c(Dog, Cat, Bird, Rat, Fox)
Y$Column1 = c(NA, 453, NA, NA, 3550, 9421, NA, 4200)
Y$Column2 = c(22, NA, 10, 150, 3550, NA, NA, 4200)
Y$Column3 = c(NA, Badger, Dog, NA, NA, NA, Fox, Mouse)
Y$Column4 = c(NA, 4500, 12345, 54, NA, 5555, 321, 65, 20)
```

From the above I would want to return 5 rows (one for each of the rows in X), along with 3 columns (the 3 original columns of X plus the 4th column of Y). The other three columns in Y are only useful for matching. As in the above example, in my data there is no way of completing a full (or close to full) match without joining on all three matches. I have been searching ways to do this for ages with no luck but I'm quite new to R so sorry if I'm being  stupid.

My code at the moment:

```
merged_pvga <- left_join(merged_pvga, sherpa, by = c("issn1" = "issn_print"))
merged_pvga <- left_join(merged_pvga, sherpa, by = c("issn1" = "issn_electronic"))
merged_pvga <- left_join(merged_pvga, sherpa, by = (c("journal_title" = "title")))
merged_pvga$id_all <- paste(merged_pvga$id.x, merged_pvga$id.y, merged_pvga$id)
merged_pvga$subject_all <- paste(merged_pvga$subject.x, merged_pvga$subject.y, merged_pvga$subject)
```

etc. for other columns

Comment: Better pivot such columns in both dfs before joining them.

Comment: I dont really get what you want to do. Can you provide example data and expected output? Also, if you want OR logic you can use the symbol "|"

Comment: Hi Anil - what do you mean by pivoting them?

Comment: Hi maarvd, I tried running a left_join with both OR and | but it didn't allow me to run it. I also couldn't find any examples of it being done by searching online, so I don't know if it is possible to do. I will think about how to provide example data and expected output. Thanks

Comment: @Tom `data.table::melt` or `dplyr::pivot_longer` columns.  That will merge all values in single column

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks for clarifying. I still don't understand how that would work with/ help the left join but I will read up on pivot_longer and try to work it out

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do.  "The only way to merge X and Y fully is to match X$Column1 with Y$Column1 OR Y$Column2, OR X$Column2 with Y$Column3."  What do you mean by merging fully? Using left_join() twice seems the right approach for that. You just have to select columns you want (and potentially select rows you want as well) before you merge and/or decide on what to do about duplicated variables (with "suffix" option) etc.

Comment: Thanks @KM_83. By merging fully I mean matching as many of the rows in X with corresponding rows in Y. In my real data the first column match matches on about 70% of the rows, the second gets me a further 20% and the third a further 15%. So I can match about 95% but only with three left_joins as you say. I think I have done everything your suggesting - but I don't know how I could use the suffix option to deal with duplicated variables? I thought that the suffix option just controls the names of the duplicated columns?

Comment: Hi @Tom  after matching 95% of the data with three left_joins, what is the problem remaining then?  You said "three versions of each column from Y in the merged data.", so I thought using suffix option may help.

Comment: @KM_83 the remaining problem is that I have three columns for every column that has been brought in from the second dataset and I need to have only one value for each row for each of the original columns. As I said I've tried to use paste, unite, and coalesce, but they either haven't worked or I've been left with a concatenated string which is pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of left-join data `Y` with `X` using `X` twice on variable `ColumnA` and then on variable `ColumnB`.

Note:

- `Y` and `X` share two variables `ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, so that after each left-join, you want to combine the columns that are not used as the join-key (for example, after joining on `ColumnA`, combine `ColumnB`'s of the two datasets).
- Be sure to know want to do about potential overlap that may emerge by joining twice on two different variables. The example below prioritize the first left-join in that those already joined from `X` are excluded in the second left-join.

```r
library(dplyr)

X = tibble(id_x=1:5)
Y = tibble(id_y=1:8)  
X$ColumnA = c(10, 150, 3550, 9421, 22000)
X$ColumnB = c('Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Rat', 'Fox')
Y$ColumnA = c(NA, 453, NA, NA, 3550, 9421, NA, 4200)
Y$Column2 = c(22, NA, 10, 150, 3550, NA, NA, 4200)
Y$ColumnB = c(NA, 'Badger', 'Dog', NA, NA, NA, 'Fox', 'Mouse')
Y$Column4 = c(NA, 4500, 12345, 54, NA, 5555, 321, 65)

replace_na_with_blank <- function(df, varnames) {
  for (varname in varnames) {
    df[is.na(df[[varname]]), varname] <- ""
  }
  return(df)
}

concat_columns <- function(df, v1, v2) {
  idx_na <- df[[v1]]==""
  df[[v1]][idx_na] <- paste(df[[v1]][idx_na], df[[v2]][idx_na], sep='') 
  df[[v2]] <- NULL
  return(df)
}

concat_columns_num <- function(df, v1, v2) {
  idx_na <- is.na(df[[v1]])
  df[[v1]][idx_na] <- df[[v2]][idx_na]
  df[[v2]] <- NULL
  return(df)
}

merged_1 <- left_join(Y, X, by = c("ColumnA" = "ColumnA"), suffix=c("",".x"))
merged_1 = replace_na_with_blank(merged_1, c("ColumnB","ColumnB.x"))
merged_1 <- concat_columns(merged_1, "ColumnB", "ColumnB.x")
merged_1 # first merge indicator is "id_x.x"

merged_2 <- left_join(merged_1, X %>% filter(!(id_x %in% merged_1$id_x)),
                      by = c("ColumnB" = "ColumnB"), suffix=c("",".x"))
merged_2 <- concat_columns_num(merged_2, "ColumnA", "ColumnA.x")
merged_2  # second merge indicator is "id_x.x.x"
```

`merge1` is

[image: merge1]

`merge2` is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @KM_83! I was able to adapt this solution to meet my needs. I ended up (1) running all three left_joins using my original code (X, Y rather than Y, X ), (2) using the replace_na_with_blank function on all the relevant columns, (3) using a series of concat_columns functions to merge columns. I had to convert one of the columns as.character because one of the functions didn't work on numeric data. Where there were more than 2 values (e.g. id, idx, and idy) I had to do two seperate concat_columns functions (i.e. id and idx, then the result of that with idy) and this worked great.